# Restricting and extending *-homomorphisms with norm-dense subalgebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be discrete groups, and suppose that I have a surjective *-homomorphism:
$$\pi:\mathrm{C}^*(G)\to C_{\text{r}}(H).$$

Is it true that the restriction to the group algebra $\pi_{|_{\mathbb{C}G}}$ maps onto $\mathbb{C}H$? Then I feel like I can extend $\pi_{|_{\mathbb{C}G}}$ to a surjective *-homomorphism $\tilde{\pi}:\mathrm{C}^*(G)\to\mathrm{C}^*(H)$, but the tension between $\pi$ and $\tilde{\pi}$ makes me feel like something has gone wrong.

> Is the problem here with the restriction, or the extension (I don't think so), something else, or does this actually work?

The actual problem I have is  different, but I feel an answer to the above should help. Speaking generally, what I have is a surjective *-homomorphism of unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras $\pi:A_\text{u}\to B_{\text{r}}$. Both $A_{\text{u}}$ and $B_{\text{r}}$ have canonical dense *-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, with $A_{\text{u}}$ a maximal completion of $\mathcal{A}$ and $B_\text{r}$ in some sense a minimal completion of $\mathcal{B}$. I want to restrict $\pi$ to $\pi_{|_{\mathcal{A}}}$ to give a *-homomorphism $\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ and then extend to $A_{\text{u}}\to B_{\text{u}}$.

(In fact $A_\text{u}$ is a certain universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra and $B_{\text{r}}=C_{\text{r}}(S_N^+)$, and I am trying to show that either $A_{\text{u}}=C_\text{u}(S_N^+)$ or it doesn't admit a compact quantum group structure... because if it did admit a compact quantum group structure, say $A_{\text{u}}=C_{\text{u}}(\mathbb{G})$, then it would admit a dense Hopf*-algebra $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G})$, and we would end up with $\mathbb{G}=S_N^+$ after all if we could restrict and extend as above.)

Comment: No problem with extending indeed, but I don't think it is true that your restriction maps the dense subspace to the dense subspace, although I cannot come up with a quick counterexample.

Comment: @J.DeRo I am wondering is there anything like a universal property saying that $\pi$ has to factor through $\mathrm{C}^*(H)$?

Comment: Do your maps preserve the comultiplications? Because in that case your original question has affirmative answer.

Comment: @J.DeRo If you go down to the generalisation, or to the actual problem, there is a priori no quantum group structure... but actually for what I want you can assume there is and the original *-homo is comultiplication preserving.

Comment: I figured from context that this would be an assumption in your case. In general, if $A= C(G)$ and $B= C(H)$ with $G,H$ compact quantum groups and if $\pi: C(G)\to C(H)$ realises $H$ as a quantum subgroup of $G$ (i.e. $\pi$ is a surjective, unital, coproduct-preserving $*$-homomorphism), then $\pi(\mathcal{O}(G))\subseteq \mathcal{O}(H)$. Proof: if $U\in \mathcal{O}(G)\odot B(K)$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $G$, then $(\pi\odot \iota)(U)$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $H$. In particular, matrix coefficients of $G$ are sent to matrix coefficients of $H$.

Comment: @J.DeRo source is at universal level, and target at reduced level.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Apply this general result to $G= G_u$ and $H= H_r$. The result I mention holds for arbitrary compact quantum groups, no reduced or universal assumptions. These are special cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context in the question and the comments, it appears that the OP is after the following result:

**Proposition**: Let $\mathbb{G}$ and $\mathbb{H}$ be two compact quantum groups and $\pi: C(\mathbb{G})\to C(\mathbb{H})$ a surjective unital, coproduct-preserving $*$-homomorphism. Then $\pi(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G}))= \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{H})$ with $\mathcal{O}(-)$ the dense Hopf $*$-subalgebras.

**Proof**: If $x\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G})$, we find a finite-dimensional representation $U\in B(K)\odot \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G})$ and $\omega \in B(K)_*$ such that $x= (\omega \odot \iota)(U)$. Then we have
$$\pi(x) = \pi((\omega \odot \iota)(U))= (\omega\odot \iota)(\iota \odot \pi)(U)\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{H})$$
where we used that $(\iota \odot \pi)(U)$ is a representation of $\mathbb{H}$ since
$$(\iota \odot\Delta_{\mathbb{H}})((\iota \odot \pi)(U)) = (\iota \odot \pi \odot \pi)(\iota \odot \Delta_{\mathbb{G}})(U) = (\iota \odot \pi\odot \pi)(U_{12}U_{13}) = (\iota \odot \pi)(U)_{12}(\iota \odot \pi)(U)_{13}.$$
This shows that $\pi(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G}))\subseteq \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{H})$.

Next, note that $A=\pi(\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{G}))$ is dense in $C(\mathbb{H})$ and it is a Hopf $^*$-subalgebra of $C(\mathbb{H})$ (meaning that $\Delta_{\mathbb{H}}(A)\subseteq A\odot A$ and with the restriction of the coproduct $A$ becomes a Hopf $^*$-algebra). Necessarily, it must follow that $A=\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{H})$, by Theorem 5.1 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010248).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, let me give a counter example to the question stated in the question. Consider $G=H=\mathbb{Z}$ so $C^*(G), C^*_r(H)$ are both identified with $C(S^1)$, where $S^1$ denotes the unit circle $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$. Moreover, the group algebras $\mathbb{C}G$ and $\mathbb{C}H$ are both identified with the dense $*$-subalgebra of trigonometric polynomials, i.e. the subalgebra of functions of the form $z\mapsto\sum_{k=-N}^N\alpha_kz^k$, where $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha_k\in\mathbb{C}$, i.e. if $\zeta$ denotes the identity map $\zeta(z):=z$, then $A$ is the linear span of $\{\zeta^k: k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Now take even some automorphism of $C(S^1)$, which by Gelfand duality is necessarily of the form $h_*:C(S^1)\to C(S^1)$, where $h\in\mathrm{Homeo}(S^1)$, i.s. $h_*(f)=f\circ h$ for all $f\in C(S^1)$. Clearly, $h_*(\zeta)=h$, since
$$h_*(\zeta)(z)=(\zeta\circ h)(z)=\zeta(h(z))=h(z)$$
so a counter-example is immediate if one takes $h\in\mathrm{Homeo}(S^1)$ be a map that is not a trigonometric polynomial. Now I can't write down any such $h$ but they surely must exist...  (e.g. take any weird self-map of a small interval that preserves the endpoints, this will induce a homeomorphism of an arc of the circle that preserves the endpoints, then extend this by identity on the rest of the circle.. [more here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715569/mathrmhomeos1-and-the-mapping-class-group))